# Remove all characters in a row with re.sub python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to edit the data to replace ALL characters before a set point. Currently I have got this far with Python but this gives me a error "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

Here is the data set before and what I am trying to achieve:

```
Header 1,Header 2,Header 3,Header 4,Header 5 
1,2,3,4,DESCRIPTION
1,2,3,4,DEffffSCRIPTION
1,2,3,4,aaaaDESCRIPTION
1,2,3,4,<>DESCRIPTION
```

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
Header 1,Header 2,Header 3,Header 4,Header 5 
1,2,3,4,SCRIPTION
1,2,3,4,SCRIPTION
1,2,3,4,SCRIPTION
1,2,3,4,SCRIPTION
```

If you can help fix the TypeError in the re.sub or if you can help overall that would be great thank you.

Here is my python code.

```
import csv
import re

with open('2.csv', "r") as inFile:
    reader = csv.reader(inFile)
    for row in reader:
        row[4](re.sub(r'.*SC', r'SC.*', row[4]))
```

Comment: You're trying to *call* `row[4]`, which is a string - that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just have a small syntax error on this line.

```
row[4](re.sub(r'.*SC', r'SC.*', row[4]))
```

row[4] is a string, so you can't call re.sub on it like that. You need to store the output of re.sub in a variable.

```
subbed_row = re.sub(r'.*SC', r'SC.*', row[4])
```

And from there figure out how you want to write that back into the csv.

Comment: Perfect thank you I understand what I was doing wrong now as soon as I can mark it as an answer I will :)